# Azure Redis Cache Geo Replication

Tags: azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

I have just setup a Redis Geo Replication between two redis caches, and now i am wondering what it is capable of. As I can see it:

1. I can only read and write to the primary redis cache
2. I can only read from the secondary

If a outrage is happening, the only way to write to the secondary, is to

1. manually remove the link
2. change the connection strings to secondary redis cache from all places where i write, to point to the secondary

Is this correctly understood? As I see it, the redis cache in Azure is only for Disaster Recovery, and not HA, or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you consider using CRDT? https://redislabs.com/docs/under-the-hood/

Comment: @GuyKorland I don't think I can configure that using the Redis I Azure. I don't install it myself. I only link servers through ARM in Azure.

Comment: You have a managed solution on Azure https://redislabs.com/partner/microsoft/